# Firebase reference without uid

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to create a reference to my firebase database and send the user.uid, but not write to that path in the database. Is this possible?

```
var dbObj = firebase.database().ref().child(`match/${user.uid}/${randomID}`);
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
return dbObj.update({
    // Set the interested value in the db
    [milliseconds]: 'text'
});
```

So i am using the user.uid to verify the user is logged in an valid through the firebase database rules. I match that with $uid and this works.

```
"match": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
  }
}
```

But what i want to write to the database location of: `../match/randomID/otherData` INSTEAD of `../match/userID/randomID/otherData`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. It sounds like a solution where I am unclear what the problem is (a so-called [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Can you explain in other words what the goal/intended result of this code is? E.g. if you think of this snippet of code as a function, what would the name of that function be?

Comment: Im asking is there a way to send the uid to firebase for rule authentication but NOT write to the database path that includes the uid. Example was in the last line of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a reference to your Firebase database and send the user.uid without writing to that path.

Say for example you have a `spaceships` path, where the child keys are spaceship IDs and the values are shapeship objects (which might have keys like weight, cost, launch_date, and `creator_id`, which is the user id of that spaceship's creator)

Your rules could look something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "spaceships": {
      "$spaceship_id": {
        // everyone can retrieve the data here
        ".read": true,
        // only the creator can edit this spaceship
        ".write": "data.child('creator_id').val() === $auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the uid of whoever is logged in has no effect in determining who can read a spaceship object (because *anyone* can). The uid value is still used to determine who can write to that path (based on the `creator_id` child key), but it is **not** included in the path you are checking, `/spaceships/$spaceship_id`.